# Cannot see much less mount SD card Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ubuntu, mount, sd-card

I can't see an SD card in Ubuntu 16.10, so I can't attempt to mount it. I've done this before, I tried tailing `dmesg`, locating it with `fdisk -l`, `lsblk`, etc. It is nowhere. I finally installed `hardinfo` and don't see my SD card reader anywhere. So I don't think I have a chance of trying to mount it. Then I see threads like this:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1922115

Is this a known problem with Ubuntu? Do I really need an external SD card reader? Is it a hardware problem or a Ubuntu driver problem?

Thank you.

Comment: That guy in the thread "use a micro sd card in my Android phone", are you trying to use an android phone as a complicated usb adapter? Is your card in a usb reader? Do any other cards work in the same reader?

Comment: How is the card formatted? If exFAT, install fuse: *sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils*